# How to fail Phing without triggering backtrace

Tags: exception, phing

Before my main phing task runs, it first checks that all required properties have been set. If a property is missing or invalid, it calls a FailTask to end execution - which works.

```
<if>
  <equals arg1="${build.db.host}" arg2="" />
  <then>
    <fail msg="build.db.host is empty." />
  </then>
</if>
```

Alas, the FailTask throws a BuildException (with the msg), which throws an 'error in IfTask' - both of which are displayed twice, with their backtraces, giving me a 60-line screen dump for a one line message!

Is there a way to suppress the backtraces, or to catch (and discard) the exceptions? Ideally, I'd see something like:

```
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/build.xml:728:6: build.db.host is empty
Total time: 0.3351 seconds
```

I'm running the latest version of Phing, from the commandline in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

The backtrace has been cleaned up as part of http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1087 (will be released in version 2.9.0). Thanks for the question!